# I need to find the Nth instance of something

Tags: t-sql

I'm writing a T-SQL database to help me identify trends with football (soccer) statistics.

I've got several rows of data per match, each row signifying an event such as a goal, or a corner.

I'm trying to work out who wins the corner races for each match to 3, 5, 7 & 9 corners.

I just cannot even think of a method to employ for this. Can anyone help?

I've tried looking at case statements and temp tables, but just can't find a way to get what I want

The data would look something like this

```
Event   Team    Time (mins)
corner  home    32
corner  home    78
corner  away    86
corner  home    12
corner  away    89
corner  away    36
```

So I would want to find the 3rd, 5th, 7th and 9th instance (if they exist) of each home corner and the same for the away corners.  The lower of the two times for each category would therefore win the race if that makes sense.

In the above example the Home team would win the race because it's third corner occurred in the 78th minute, whereas the third away corner was in the 89th minute.

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
select e.*, 
(select count(*) from events
  where team = e.team and event = e.event and time < e.time) + 1 counter
from events e 
order by e.time
```

you get in chronological order all the events and for each event a counter up to that time. 
 You can use it like this:

```
select top 1 t.team
from (
  select e.*, 
    (select count(*) from events
    where team = e.team and event = e.event and time < e.time) + 1 counter
  from events e
) t
where event = 'corner' and counter = 3
order by t.time
```

to get the winning team of the 3 corners.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ac70e26a3ec94bf4c38f6038768f9a00).

Comment: Absolute superstar.  Thank you so much!  Been tying myself up in knots all night over this!!!

Comment: If this solved your problem consider accepting this answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for the Home team:

SELECT TOP 9 * FROM Your_Table ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(ORDER BY Time)  AS RowNum WHERE RowNum = 3 OR RowNum = 5 OR RowNum = 7 OR RowNum = 9 AND Team = 'Home'

You'd create something similar for the away team...